# "The" for the first time only

Tags: articles, definite-articles, zero-article

A quote from [LibreOffice user manual](https://documentation.libreoffice.org/assets/Uploads/Documentation/en/WG6.0/WG60-WriterGuideLO.pdf):

> Turning on hyphenation for the Default Style paragraph style affects all other
>   paragraph styles that are based on Default Style. You can individually change other
>   styles so that hyphenation is not active; for example, you might not want headings to
>   be hyphenated. Any styles that are not based on Default Style are not affected. For
>   more on paragraph styles, see Chapters 8 and 9 in this book.

For what reason is "the" used before "Default Style"   for the first time, but not used any further?

Comment: 'the' relates to 'paragraph style' in this instance

Comment: side quest: should a hyphen be placed between Default and Style? (as in "Turning on hyphenation for the Default-Style paragraph style..")

Comment: @Bora No, the hyphen is not required here.

Comment: @Bora As per [Uri Granta's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/516950/290633), 'Default Style' is the name of the paragraph style.  You can write "Give me the Harry Potter book", or "Give me the 'Harry Potter' book", but not "Give me the Harry-Potter book".

Answer (score 40, accepted):

"Deafult Style" is being used as a proper noun here, which is reasonable as it's the name of a particular style. As such it doesn't use an article. However, in the first example it is being used as an adjunct, modifying "paragraph style"; the article "the" is linking to "paragraph style", not to "Default Style" itself. ("*Which paragraph style? The Default Style paragraph style.*")

It's like saying "I went to *the* Disney World *resort*" versus "I went to Disney World".

Comment: I would remark that it could be written as "for the paragraph style, Default Style, affects" Or "for Default Style the paragraph style affects".

Comment: @DanD. That sounds like a completely incorrect rewriting to me. In the original, the subject is the gerund phrase "Turning on hyphenation for the Default Style paragraph style" - the action of turning on hyphenation is the thing that affects other styles. Your second rewrite is a reasonable sentence but means something different; your first attempt I can't make heads or tails of.

Comment: The first is the comma inversion of the second. "Name Default Style Title the paragraph style" "Title the paragraph style, Name Default Style,". A better example would perhaps be "Conan the barbarian" vs "the barbarian, Conan," rather than "the Conan barbarian".

Comment: Could _Default Style_ and _paragraph_ also be hyphenated to clarify this association?

Comment: @DanD. Try "...for the paragraph style of Default Style affects...", or "...for Default Style's paragraph style affects..." - to make it clearer, you *could* put the "Default Style" name in quotes.

Comment: _"I went to the Disney World resort"_ - does it mean that _the_ is used even if the reader don't know about such resort, i.e. this resort is mentioned for the first time? (And a lot of thanks for the awesome answer.)

Comment: @johnc.j. Yes. Even if it wasn't previously mentioned, the resort is being uniquely identified by the speaker, so uses 'the'. If there were lots of Disney World resorts and it wasn't obvious from context which one you were referring to then you would instead say 'a'.

Answer (score 3):

Using the article "the" every time, or even the first time, is not strictly required. Articles are often left out in many kinds of writing. When the sentence doesn't have a noun phrase that describes the title, they aren't needed.

Think of this example of a book. You can write:

"Read the book 'Leaves of Grass.'"

or

"Read 'Leaves of Grass' because it is a great book."

Here is an example of both together:

The book "Leaves of Grass" is an example of modern American poetry. "Leaves of Grass" exalted the body and the material world, according to Wikipedia.

In this particular case, "Default Style" is a name. It doesn't need an article, but the writer also used an identifying phrase in the first sentence -- "paragraph style" -- which needed "the" article. Later sentences just used the title. It might have been better if the name had been in quotes.

Comment: You can also write your example in the same form as the question - "Read the 'Leaves of Grass' book"

Comment: Yes, good point.